# Are static variables in a base class shared by all derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

If I have something like

```
class Base {
    static int staticVar;
}

class DerivedA : public Base {}
class DerivedB : public Base {}
```

Will both `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` share the same `staticVar` or will they each get their own?

If I wanted them to each have their own, what would you recommend I do?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

They will each share the same instance of `staticVar`.

In order for each derived class to get their own static variable, you'll need to declare another static variable with a different name.

You could then use a virtual pair of functions in your base class to get and set the value of the variable, and override that pair in each of your derived classes to get and set the "local" static variable for that class. Alternatively you could use a single function that returns a reference:

```
class Base {
    static int staticVarInst;
public:
    virtual int &staticVar() { return staticVarInst; }
}
class Derived: public Base {
    static int derivedStaticVarInst;
public:
    virtual int &staticVar() { return derivedStaticVarInst; }
}
```

You would then use this as:

```
staticVar() = 5;
cout << staticVar();
```

Comment: (Note that the CRTP also allows derived class to get their own version of some static variable.)

Comment: I think I'll go with the virtual functions, but just to clarify, if I declare a static variable with the same name in a derived class, it will basically override the base class right? So I can count on its existance in all derived classes...

Comment: You can in fact declare a static variable with the same name in a derived class. If you do this, I would qualify each reference to that variable with its class name, ie: `virtual int &staticVar() { return Derived::staticVarInst; }`

Answer (score 46):

To ensure that each class has its own static variable, you should use the ["Curiously recurring template pattern" (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    static int staticVar;
};

template <typename T> int Base<T>::staticVar(0);

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA> {};
class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB> {};
```

Comment: CRTP not really involved in there, it is more the specialization of the base class; could work with anything like Base<tag_type0> and Base<tag_type1>. But good thing to plug in the discussion the CRTP for those who do not know it ;)

Comment: This is indeed the CRTP (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); inheriting from a templated base class with your own class name as the argument is the definition of CRTP.

Comment: I know that I a am **very** late to the discussion, but it may help fellow googlers that are learning just like myself. Can anybody point the advantages/disadvanteges between this answer and the accepted answer?

Comment: Accepted answer requires you to declare a new static variable and the access methods. This answer is more elegant : you write only once and get as many static variable as you need : one per template specialization.

Answer (score 3):

They will share the same instance.

You'll need to declare separate static variables for each subclass, or you could consider a simple static map in which you could store variables that are referenced by derived classes.

---

**Edit**: A possible solution to this would be to define your base class as a template.  Having a static variable defined in this template would mean that each derived class will have it's own instance of the static.

Comment: In this case, by "derived" you mean Base<A> would have a different static var than Base<B>, but Derived<A> would still share with Base<A> no?

Comment: There is no template called `Derived`. Instead, in this case, it's `template<typename> struct Base { static int staticVar; protected: ~Base() { } }; template<typename D> int Base<D>::staticVar; struct DerivedA : Base<DerivedA> { }; struct DerivedB : Base<DerivedB> { };`. Now there are two static variables, which you can access with `DerivedB::staticVar` and `DerivedA::staticVar`

Answer (score 3):

There is only one `staticVar` in your case:  `Base::staticVar`

When you declare a static variable in a class, the variable is declared for that class alone.  In your case, DerivedA can't even see `staticVar` (since it's private, not protected or public), so it doesn't even know there is a `staticVar` variable in existence.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, C++ has no virtual static data members. There are several ways to simulate this, more or less:

- [@GregHewgill's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390922/1593077) has you replicate the static variable in each derived class; this solution is simple, straightforward and doesn't introduce additional classes, but I don't like this one since it's verbose, and you have to be rather disciplined with it.
- @MarkIngram suggested a [CRTP-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3829887/1593077), which saves you most of the typing; however, it messes up the inheritance structure, because what were previously subclasses of A are no longer really related as classes. After all, two templated types with the same name but different template arguments could be just any two types.

I suggest a different [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)-based solution, using a [mix-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept) class:

```
 class A {
      virtual const int& Foo() const = 0;
 }

 template <typename T>
 class FooHolder {
      static int foo_;
      const int& Foo() const override { return foo_; }
 }

 class B : A, virtual FooHolder<B> { }

 class C : B, virtual FooHolder<C> { }
```

The only thing you need to do in a subclass is also indicate the mix-in inheritance. There might be some virtual inheritance caveats I'm missing here (as I rarely use it).

Note that you either have to instantiate and initialize each subclass' static variable somewhere, or you can make it an `inline` variable (C++17) and initialize it within the template.

<sub>This answer was adapted from my answer to a [dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213860/1593077).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question has already been answered but I would like to provide a small example of inheritance with static members. This is a very nice way to demonstrate the usefulness as well as what is happening with the static variables and the respective constructors.

**FooBase.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_BASE_H
#define FOO_BASE_H

#include <string>

class FooBase {
protected:
    std::string _nameAndId;
private:
    std::string _id;
    static int _baseCounter;

public:
    std::string idOfBase();
    virtual std::string idOf() const = 0;

protected:
    FooBase();    
};

#endif // !FOO_BASE_H
```

**FooBase.cpp**

```
#include "FooBase.h"
#include <iostream>

int FooBase::_baseCounter = 0;

FooBase::FooBase() {
    _id = std::string( __FUNCTION__ ) + std::to_string( ++_baseCounter );
    std::cout << _id << std::endl;
}

std::string FooBase::idOfBase() {
    return _id;
}

std::string FooBase::idOf() const {
    return "";
} // empty
```

**DerivedFoos.h**

```
#ifndef DERIVED_FOOS_H
#define DERIVED_FOOS_H

#include "FooBase.h"

class DerivedA : public FooBase {
private:    
    static int _derivedCounter;

public:
    DerivedA();

    std::string idOf() const override;
};

class DerivedB : public FooBase {
private:
    static int _derivedCounter;

public:
    DerivedB();

    std::string idOf() const override;
};

#endif // !DERIVED_FOOS_H
```

**DerivedFoos.cpp**

```
#include "DerivedFoos.h"
#include <iostream>

int DerivedA::_derivedCounter = 0;
int DerivedB::_derivedCounter = 0;

DerivedA::DerivedA() : FooBase() {
    _nameAndId = std::string( __FUNCTION__ ) + std::to_string( ++DerivedA::_derivedCounter );
    std::cout << _nameAndId << std::endl;
}

std::string DerivedA::idOf() const {
    return _nameAndId;
}    

DerivedB::DerivedB() : FooBase() {
    _nameAndId = std::string( __FUNCTION__ ) + std::to_string( ++DerivedB::_derivedCounter );
    std::cout << _nameAndId << std::endl;
}

std::string DerivedB::idOf() const {
    return _nameAndId;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "DerivedFoos.h"

int main() {
    DerivedA a1;  
    DerivedA a2;
    DerivedB b1;
    DerivedB b2;

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

If `__FUNCTION__` is not working for you in your constructors then you can use something similar that can replace it such as `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `__func__`, or manually type out each class's name `:(`.

Answer (score 2):

The sample code given by @einpoklum is not working as it is because of the missing initialization of the static member `foo_`, missing inheritance in `FooHolder` declaration, and missing `public` keywords since we are dealing with classes. Here is the fixed version of it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    virtual const int& Foo() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class FooHolder : public virtual A {
public:
    const int& Foo() const override { return foo_; }
    static int foo_;
};

class B : public virtual A, public FooHolder<B> { };
class C : public virtual A, public FooHolder<C> { };

template<>
int FooHolder<B>::foo_(0);
template<>
int FooHolder<C>::foo_(0);

int main()
{
  B b;
  C c;
  std::cout << b.Foo() << std::endl;
  std::cout << c.Foo() << std::endl;
}
```