# How to initialize static members in derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

Well, apparently, I cannot. But that's my problem. Maybe it's a design issue and I'm getting the whole thing wrong.

I would like to have a class member initialized differently within each derived class. Imagine I have an object of type `Device`. This `Device` is just an interface used by the application code, because the actual devices are just one of two types, `DeviceA` or `DeviceB`. There are some features common to all devices, like, say, the name. That should be then a class member, shouldn't it? So I'd have:

```
class Device {
    static std::string sm_name;
}
```

But each family device has its own name. *How could I initialize the name to a different value for each derived class?* Is the design wrong? Should the name property not be a class member?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are static variables in a base class shared by all derived classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390913/are-static-variables-in-a-base-class-shared-by-all-derived-classes)

Comment: Ouch! I should read more carefully the answers O:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should the name property not be a class member?

Each family device should, most likely, have it's own, private static member.  You could use a virtual method to return the proper name on a device instance.

Comment: Ok, I see then, no other choice than having each derived class define its own member.

Answer (score 2):

why not just have a virtual member function which returns the name, and implement it in the derived class to return the correct name?

e.g.

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual std::string name() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
virtual std::string name() { return "typeB"; }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
virtual std::string name() { return "typeC"; }
};
```

Comment: You'll want the function to be virtual, though. And for safety, `A`s destructor should be either virtual or protected.

Comment: sorry, I missed off the virtual in my haste :-(