# Static variable inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want static variables in derived classes, so I want to make some stuff in a base class. Base class would be virtual. Is it possible?

```
class Base {
public:
    static const int x;
    void f() {
        return x;
    }
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : virtual Base {
public:
    void g() {}
};
const int Derived1::x = 1;

class Derived2 : virtual Base {
public:
    void g() {}
};
const int Derived2::x = 2;

...

Derived1 a;
Derived2 b;
a.f() == 1; // should be true
b.f() == 2; // should be true
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make each derived class have it's own instance of a static variable?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, I've found solution by rephrasing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390913/are-static-variables-in-a-base-class-shared-by-all-derived-classes

Comment: I'm closing this as dupe then.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, no, C++ has no virtual statics. What you can do instead is use a non-static getter method:

```
 class A {
      virtual const int& Foo() const = 0;
 }

 class B : A {
      static int foo_;
      const int& Foo() const override { return foo_; }
 }
 int B::foo_ { 1 };
```

You can "automate" this with a [mix-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept) class defined using [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp):

```
 class A {
      virtual const int& Foo() const = 0;
 }

 template <typename T>
 class FooHolder {
      static int foo_;
      const int& Foo() const override { return foo_; }
 }

 class B : A, virtual FooHolder<B> {
      // other stuff
 }
```

This way, the only thing you need to do in a subclass is also indicate the mix-in inheritance. There might be some virtual inheritance caveats I'm missing here (as I rarely use it).

Another option, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3829887/1593077), is to make class `A` templated itself, so that each B inherits from a different A. But that will break your inheritance structure.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no notion of `virtual` member variables -- `static` or regular. It has `virtual` member functions.

It will be best to encapsulate the `static` member variables and access them through `virtual` member functions.

```
class Base {
public:
    // static const int x;

    void f() {
       int x = getX();
       // Use x
    }

    virtual int getX() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : virtual Base {
  static const int x;
  public:
    virtual int getX() { return x;}
    void g() {}
};
const int Derived1::x = 1;
```

Unless there is another compelling reason to keep `Derived1::x` as a member variable, you can remove it and simplify `Derived1`.

```
class Derived1 : virtual Base {
  public:
    virtual int getX() { return 1;}
    void g() {}
};
```

Comment: With this code, you need to override `f()` to return the `Derived1::x`

Comment: @Emadpres, thanks for the prod. I updated the answer to deal with just `x`.